# MIME Not Supported Error on Webpage

Tags: webpage, mime-types, mime-headers

I have a strange issue on some but not all machines I am currently deploying across a large network. All are the same base image except some have obviously had things installed since this has come to light.

The error itself is MIME_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED with no other information (as below)

[image]

I have tried to troubleshoot this in two ways, using Fiddler to track all HTTP traffic from a working PC and a none working but unable to see the 'troublesome' part of the site. I have also compared the MIME registry database list from both machines but no differences except one program which I have installed but did not help the problem.

Any other way I can troubleshoot this further?

The link is:

https://paymentservices.bacs.co.uk/online/newbacs/loginBrowser.do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Spoke to my Bacs provider (Barclays) They sent me new software version 4.4 to install... if you have other bacs provider software on there E.G Bottomline you have to tell them and they will send different software to by an email link and this corrects the problem. took 5 mins to sort hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nick, to be honest I forgot about this post as we did fix the issue by installing another version of the software however I believe we went back down to 4.0 from 4.2 maybe (was a little while ago now). But yes looks like one of the versions is a bit buggy.

Answer (score 2):

I had a user experience the same issue using eSigner version 4.4. Poking around for some differences between the 4.4 install and a 4.2 install that worked on another machine, I found that the config.reg file from the 4.2 install had the following entry that was not present in the local.conf on the 4.4 install:

```
"ISPI.mode.support"=dword:00000001
```

I added this to local.conf and it now works.

Some results from google appear to imply that this setting is to do with browser plugins, so this change would seem to make sense.

Comment: This fixed it for us, too. Thanks! For posterity, our path/version was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Gemalto\eSigner6\plugin\local.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Check the version you are using and ask your bank if its the right version - just had this problem and Barclays had sent us the wrong version - we were using 6421 corporate and getting the same error message - we contacted BACS and they told us ask Barclays about the version - removed the corp version installed 6421 IS and now working fine

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was going to Control Panel and change it to Always Allow JNPL File/MIME Association in JAVA, Advanced Tab.